# Most efficient way to do (lo <= k && k <= hi) ? 1 : 0 for k a numpy array, lo, hi constants

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, numpy

I have a large numpy array `k`, of unspecified shape, and I want to construct an identically shaped array `d` which is 1.0 when the corresponding entry in `k` is between two constants `lo` and `hi`, 0.0 otherwise.  (Because of what the larger code is doing, I do *not* want a Boolean-valued array.)

The obvious way to do this is

```
d = np.ones_like(k)
d[np.less(k, lo)] = 0
d[np.greater(k, hi)] = 0
```

However, the `np.less` and `np.greater` calls involve the creation of large scratch Boolean arrays, and I have measured this to be a significant overhead.  Is there a way to perform this operation that does not involve creating any large scratch objects, while remaining fully vectorized?

Comment: If the large scratch arrays are a big enough problem that you need to get rid of them, you're going to have the same problem with most of the usual NumPy techniques. NumPy is quite fond of building giant scratch arrays.

Comment: I don't think there's a way to avoid any scratch arrays for this operation when using plain NumPy. You may need to look to C (writing custom ufuncs), Cython or Numba.

Answer (score 1):

As others said, numpy *is* heavy on temporary buffers and it does not offer much control over it. If memory footprint is really a blocker, you can drop in your own little routine. For instance,

```
def process(x, lo, hi):
    """ lo <= x < hi ? 1.0 : 0.0."""
    x_shape = x.shape
    xx = np.ascontiguousarray(x).ravel()
    out = np.empty_like(xx)
    _process(xx, lo, hi, out)
    return out.reshape(x_shape)
```

where `_process` is in cython:

```
%%cython --annotate

import cython

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
def _process(double[::1] x, double lo, double hi, double[::1] out):
    """ lo <= x < hi ? 1.0 : 0.0.""" 
    cdef:
        Py_ssize_t j
        double xj

    for j in range(x.shape[0]):
        xj = x[j]
        if lo <= xj < hi:
            out[j] = 1.0
        else:
            out[j] = 0.0
```

Here I used jupyter notebook (hence the funny `%%cython` syntax). In real project you need to throw in a `setup.py` to compile the extension etc. Whether the benefit from doing this is worth the hassle is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can create boolean array based upon the comparison and then convert to float type, all in one go, like so -

```
d = ((k >=lo) & (k <= hi)).astype(float)
```

Comment: That still creates scratch objects.  In fact, I believe it creates *more* scratch objects than what I have (I count three of them).

Comment: @zwol Yeah I was going more with the performance efficiency, as it shows some good speedup (based on a quick runtime test done at my end). In terms of memory usage, one has to profile accordingly. Yeah, I think there are three here and then one of them is assigned as the output, so it's the same as the original one if the assignment part doesn't make a copy? I guess so!

Answer (score 0):

`less` and `greater` take an `out` parameter:

```
out=np.ones_like(k)
np.less(k,80,out=out);
out &= np.greater(k,20);
# np.logical_and(np.greater(k,20),out,out=out);
```

That might end up saving one intermediate array.  Although my impression with the ufunc `out` is that it still creates a temporary array, but then just copies it to the `out`.

On a small (10x10) array, this is faster than @zwol's method, but slower than @Divakar's.  But the differences are not major.